# MySQL Campo de Busca por Array

Tags: mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

preciso criar um campo de busca do meu programa no BD em MySQL. Quero criar uma busca que filtre nomes de pessoas, mas ignorando letras duplicadas em nomes ou caracteres especiais, como apóstrofos. Por exemplo:

Quero buscar por "Ana Maria" e ele me retornar inclusive se o nome for "Anna Maria", ou buscar "Deltoro" e ele me retornar inclusive "Del'Toro".

Se não houver uma forma pré-definida para fazer isso, pensei em fazer a busca, transformando a string de busca em um array de caracteres, combinada com uma função para eliminar os caracteres especiais e as letras duplicadas, e filtrar o campo nome no MySQL por essa lista de caracteres. Por exemplo:

```
Busca = 'Anna Maria'
Array = (a,n,m,r,i)

MySQL select * pessoas where... array está dentro do valor do campo nome.
```

Não sei se ficou claro, mas não tenho ideia de como construir essa busca no MySQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

RESOLVIDO:

Depois de matutar bastante, percebi resolveria se passar para a busca no SQL uma string com '%' antes e depois de cada letra, substituindo também espaços, caracteres especiais e letras iguais por strings vazias (''). Então criei uma função (em PHP no caso) para ajustar:

```
function str_busca($x) {
        $x_array = str_split($x);
        $nome_ajustado = '';
        foreach ($x_array as $i => $letra) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                $letra = '%'.$letra.'%';
            } else {
                if ($letra == " " or $letra == "-" or $letra == "'" or $letra == $x_array[$i - 1]) {
                    $letra = '';
                } else {
                    $letra .= '%';
                }
            }
            $nome_ajustado .= $letra;
        }
        return $nome_ajustado;
    }
```